# Subscribers are required to opt-in before the price decrease, or it is only for price increases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store

Recently I have read the news of an Update to subscription notifications, according to it, when an auto-renewable subscription price is increased, subscribers must opt-in before the price increase is applied.

So Subscribers are required to opt-in before the price decrease, or it is only for price increases?

Your answers will be helpful.

Ref. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=tpgp89cl

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's only for price increases.

And FYI, rules have changed 2 days ago concerning price increases: https://9to5mac.com/2022/05/16/app-store-increased-prices-auto-renewable-subscriptions/